# Picking two radio buttons to show/hide divs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two radio button categories that are broken down into showing/hiding different input fields. I'm inching closer to getting it but can't seem to figure it out completely.

Here are the images below:

**Selecting 'Single user' and 'Live Session' works perfectly.**

[image]

**Selecting 'Single user' and 'Remote Session' works perfectly.**

[image]

**Selecting 'Team' and 'Live session' works perfectly.**

[image]

**When selecting 'Team' and 'Remote session' - When a user clicks on both 'Team' + 'Remote Session' radio buttons at the same time, I want to be able to hide the divs (.total, .one, .two, .three, .four, .five ---> .ten). So basically all the input boxes below 'Requester Name' and 'Team Name'.**

[image]

Here is the code that I currently have:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input[name=requestType]').click(function() {
  if(this.value == 'Team')
  {
   $(".total").show();
   $(".teamname").show();
   $(".one").show();
   $(".two").show();
   $(".three").show();
   $(".four").show();
   $(".five").show();
  }
  else
  {
   $(".teams").hide();
  }
 });
 
 $("input[name=sessionType]").change(function(){
 
 });
  
 
 $("#totalUsers").change(function() {
  $('.six').hide();
  $('.seven').hide();
  $('.eight').hide();
  $('.nine').hide();
  $('.ten').hide();
  
  var selectValue = $(this).val();
  
  switch (selectValue) {
    case "six":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      break;
    case "seven":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      break;
    case "eight":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      $('.eight').show();
      break;
    case "nine":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      $('.eight').show();
      $('.nine').show();
      break;
    case "ten":
      $('.five').show();
      $('.six').show();
      $('.seven').show();
      $('.eight').show();
      $('.nine').show();
      $('.ten').show();
      break;
  }
 });
 
 $("#submit").click(function (){
  if($("#submit").hasClass("disabled")) {
   alert('Validation Failed');
  }
  else {
   AddListItem();
   return false;
  }
 });
});

function getItem() {
 
 var item = {
  Title: $("#requesterName").val(),
  TeamName: $("#teamName").val(),
  NumberOfAttendees: $("#totalUsers").val(),
        FirstName: $("#oneUser").val(),
        SecondName: $("#twoUsers").val(),
        ThirdName: $("#threeUsers").val(),
        FourthName: $("#fourUsers").val(),
        FifthName: $("#fiveUsers").val(),
        SixthName: $("#sixUsers").val(),
        SeventhName: $("#sevenUsers").val(),
        EighthName: $("#eightUsers").val(),
        NinthName: $("#nineUsers").val(),
        TenthName: $("#tenUsers").val(),
        RequestType: $("input[name=requestType]:checked").val(),
        SessionType: $("input[name=sessionType]:checked").val(),
 };
 return item;
}

function AddListItem(resources) {
 
 var item = getItem();
 
 if (item.RequestType == "Single User") {
  item.NumberOfAttendees = 'None';
 }
 
 $pnp.setup({
  baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/"
 });
 
 $pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Training").items.add(item).then(function(r){
  $("#submit").hide();
  $(".form").hide();
  $(".icon").hide();
  $("#header").hide();
  $("#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea").hide();
        $("#hidden_div").show();
  $("#cancel").hide();
 });
}
```

```css
#submit
{
 border-radius: 4px!important;
}
.ext
{
 display: none;
}
#DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea {
font-size: 3rem;
}
.one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven,
.eight, .nine, .ten {
 margin-bottom: 3px!important;
}

.form-group {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 width: 450px;
}
.form {
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
#hidden_div {
 padding-top: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 2rem!important;
}
.icon {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 25px;
 width: 150px;
 height: 140px;
}

.teams
{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
 <div class="container form">
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="requestType" class="col-form-label">Request Type:</label>
    <label for="singleUser" class="radio-inline"><input id="singleUser" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Single User" checked>Single User</label>
  <label for="teamSelection" class="radio-inline"><input id="teamSelection" type="radio" name="requestType" value="Team">Team</label>
  
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="sessionType" class="col-form-label">Session Type:</label>
    <label for="liveSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="liveSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Live Session" checked>Live Session</label>
  <label for="remoteSession" class="radio-inline"><input id="remoteSession" type="radio" name="sessionType" value="Remote Session">Remote Session</label>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="requesterName" class="col-form-label">Requester Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="requesterName" type="text" id="requesterName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: Jane Doe" required/>
  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>


 <div class="form-group row teamname teams">
   <label for="teamName" class="col-form-label">Team Name:</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="teamName" type="text" id="teamName" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid team name." placeholder="Ex: PortalHelp Team" required/>
    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group row teams total">
     <label for="totalUsers" class="col-form-label">Number of Attendees:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="totalUsers">
          <option value="Five" selected>5</option>
          <option value="Six">6</option>
          <option value="Seven">7</option>
          <option value="Eight">8</option>
          <option value="Nine">9</option>
          <option value="Ten">10</option>
        </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row one teams">
        <label for="oneUser" class="col-form-label">Names of Attendees:</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="oneUser" type="text" id="oneUser" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." placeholder="Ex: John Smith" required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group row two teams">
        <input class="form-control" name="twoUsers" type="text" id="twoUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
   </div>

      <div class="form-group row three teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="threeUsers" type="text" id="threeUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row four teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fourUsers" type="text" id="fourUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row five teams">
          <input class="form-control" name="fiveUsers" type="text" id="fiveUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row six teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sixUsers" type="text" id="sixUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row seven teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="sevenUsers" type="text" id="sevenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row eight teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="eightUsers" type="text" id="eightUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

   <div class="form-group row nine teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="nineUsers" type="text" id="nineUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row ten teams teams1">
          <input class="form-control" name="tenUsers" type="text" id="tenUsers" data-minlength="2" data-error="Please enter a valid name." required/>
          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
          <button type="button" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" name="cancelbutton" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" onclick="window.location.href='/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/Pages/Training.aspx'">Cancel</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the question/issue here?

Comment: Hi @dustytrash,

When a user clicks on both 'Team' + 'Remote Session' radio buttons at the same time, I want to be able to hide the divs (.total, .one, .two, .three, .four, .five ---> .ten). So basically all the input boxes that you see under 'Requester Name' and 'Team Name'.

Comment: I've updated the last picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css sibling selectors to do this without need for jQuery.

```
<input type="radio" name="fieldset1" value="input1"> input1
<input type="radio" name="fieldset1" value="input2"> input 2
<br>
<input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="input1"> input1
<input type="radio" name="fieldset2" value="input2"> input 2
<div>some content</div>
```

--

```
input[name="fieldset1"][value="input2"]:checked~input[name="fieldset2"][value="input2"]:checked ~ div{
  display: none;

}
```

I made this code pen to illustrate how: https://codepen.io/hasanainj/pen/ZMVwYo

Let me know if this doesn't work for your use case